Django with gunicorn: sending requests - concurrency
We've got a Django application configured with gunicorn. That means several workers are processed in parallel. Now for some functionality we need to call a service for reverse geocoding looking something like this:
    reverseGeocodingURL = s.geocodingURL + '?lat=' + str(latitude) + '&lon=' + str(longitude) + '&api_key=' + s.apiKey

Now it appears that sometimes the responses seem to be not aligned to the requests. It's probably a concurrency issue when one gunicorn worker receives the reponse of a request issued by another worker. Is this possible? And what possibilities do we have to circumvent this problem?

The problem described above was not related to gunicorn. It was a very different problem.

If it's because of concurrency, there are two ways to you solve the problem

First Way: Run only one worker process

This may cause performance issue if volume is very high.
Implementation steps: if you are using gunicorn config file then change the worker number to 1
workers = 1

if you are directly running gunicorn with command then add worker=1 in command like argumerts.
gunicorn --workers=2


Second Way: run Django with static secret key (any random secret key)

set this in your settings.py file
SECRET_KEY = '=v@drifp^(2p5l#hvm=qzlt17(4lp!n$#)_qc9lik8z1jm(stw'

Can you explain how the second solution you propose would improve the situation?

Sorry for the confusion, You can use any random key. Just make sure that, you are not generating it dynamically. As Django use this key to verify CSRF and sessions. If you use random keys with multiple worker processes, each process with have different SECRET_KEY, which will create issue in session and token verification.
